# Como alterar uma propriedade durante uma consulta LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Existe alguma forma de alterar na consulta LINQ uma propriedade da própria consulta?

Ex.: Estou fazendo uma consulta num `List<Cliente>` e quero que todos os clientes cujo `NomeFantasia` comece com **`*`** tenham o símbolo removido do nome.

Aqui está a consulta que estou fazendo. Eu pensei em fazer um `Select`, colocando todos os campos da classe na consulta, mas como eu preciso retornar um `List<Cliente>` isso não daria certo.

```
var ret = this.FindAll().Where(x => x.Id > 10).OrderBy(x => x.NomeFantasia);
```

Comment: Não entendi ainda... Você quer receber os dados e depois alterá-los na coleção original ou somente no resultado?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Até é possível mas você precisa entender que a ideia do LINQ é o estilo de programação funcional que prega a imutabilidade. E o próprio nome demonstra isso. O Q é de *query*, de **consulta**, e não de manipulação, de atualização.

Então apesar de ser possível usando alguma técnica confusa, vai contra a intenção do recurso e é melhor usar o algoritmo tradicional para fazer a manipulação. Você pode até usar o LINQ para determinar todos os elementos da coleção que atendam a condição estabelecida e mereçam a manipulação e depois manipular em um `foreach`. Muitos vão preferir fazer a consulta e manipulação em dentro do `foreach`. Neste caso é tão simples que o LINQ é descartável.

```
foreach (var item in clientes) item.NomeFantasia.Replace("*", "");
```

Ou se quiser só no início:

```
foreach (var item in clientes) item.NomeFantasia.TrimStart('*');
```

Não sei se entendi totalmente seu objetivo mas é simples assim. Mesmo que queira fazer algo um pouco diferente, a base é esta. Evidentemente que o LINQ ainda pode ser usado para fazer outros filtros. Mas se ele estiver relacionado provavelmente será melhor meter um `if` dentro do `foreach` mesmo.

Se quiser insistir:

```
var resultado = clientes.Select(item => { item.NomeFantasia.TrimStart('*'); return item; })
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Update.cs).

Mas note que a atualização não será executada neste momento. É característica do LINQ ter uma [execução atrasada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

Achei sem LINQ mais curto :)

Comment: A minha intenção era evitar o `foreach`, mas parece que não tem jeito mesmo.

Comment: Como eu disse LINQ não é solução para tudo.

Comment: É, eu percebi. Mas é que se parar pra analisar é uma questão bem simples...

Comment: O segredo é ele ser escrita, mesmo uma mudança simples, ele não é ideal. Tanto que não tem um método de extensão compatível com LINQ chamado `Write`, `Replace`, `Update`, ou algo assim. Não esqueceram, eles seriam ruins. por causar efeito colateral.

Comment: Um detalho: o AP queria remover '*' no início. Esse remove todos. Se for usar, veja se isso não é um problema.

Comment: Pronto, tem os dois. Isto é só detalhe secundário do que é mais importante na pergunta.

Comment: Isso é só detalhe @RSinohara